# Eclipse takes a long time to recognize build completion

Tags: eclipse, build, compilation

I've got a large project which is built on a remote system.  To facilitate the build within eclipse, I have a compile target with the following command:

> ssh user@server "cd /project/build; gmake -j4"

The build completes, but it takes over 5 minutes from the time the build completes, to the point in which Eclipse detects the completion of the build.  Any suggestions on how to enable earlier detection of the build completion?